# Shift Operator in integer

Tags: java, bit-shift

Somebody please explain how to to solve such task ?

```
int x = (Integer.MIN_VALUE << 1) >> 1;
```

I would like to understand how to solve the examples like that ? What I need to do if the sample contains Integer.MIN_VALUE (Integer.MAX_VALUE) ?

Comment: Wait, what specific task?

Comment: What is the actual question...?  Do you know how the shift operator works?

Comment: Is this homework? Do you need to work out the value of x after the assignment?

Comment: Yes, but I dont understand how shift operator work with Integer.Max(Min)Value ?

Comment: No. This is just question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `Integer.Max(Min)Value`.

Comment: Due to overflow, x will be 0 for the case of Integer.MIN_VALUE. In the case of Integer.MAX_VALUE x will be -1 due to sign extension from the arithmetic right shift. Maybe you should read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts

Comment: I just meant "work with Integer.MinValue" and "work with integer MaxValue"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shift operator (`y << x`) just shifts the bits of `y` to the left by 'x' places.  The right-most bit becomes `0`.  The `>>` operator shifts to the right, and the value of the left-most bit (the sign bit) is copied into the new left-most bit.

To work out your answer you need the bit pattern for the initial value (Integer.MIN_VALUE) and then do the operations to get the resulting bit pattern.  You can then convert that back to a decimal value.

Comment: So, I need to present my number 2^31 as a bit of code, and then do the operation to get the resulting bit pattern. I think that exists quick way to resolve this problem.

Comment: The quick way is to write a short program to do the work and give you the output, or do it a programmer's calculator (calc.exe in Windows is good for this).  But to actually understand what's happening it's good to do it by hand a couple of times.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could just follow short tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

In a nutshell, by doing `<<` (left shift) you move binary representation of your number to the left 
i.e. if `x = 0b0010`, then `x << 1` becomes `0b0100`, new 'zero' bit is appended to the right.

Similarily, for right shift :
if `x = 0b1010`, then `x >> 1` becomes `0b1101`, rightmost bit dissapears, new 'one' bit (depends on value of leftmost bit) is appended on the left.

You need to find out binary representation of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to resolve your puzzle, which should not be very tricky.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to understand how the bit shift operators work, I would suggest two things:

- First, read some guides on what they do: [here](http://sys.cs.rice.edu/course/comp314/10/p2/javabits.html) and [here](http://rodrigosasaki.com/2013/06/06/bit-shift-and-bitwise-operators/) for example.
- Write some code and look at the output. That way you can see how bit shift operators actually affect values like `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: but what code can show how work shift ?

Comment: Did you actually read the links I gave?

Comment: yeaр. reading right now

Answer (score 1):

The min-value is represented as `10000000000000000000000000000000`. It's 32 1's. For clarity, let's pretend we're working with only 4 bits. In this case, the `MIN_INT` would be `1000`. This will apply to 32 bits as well.

We then want to left shift `<<` by 1, which would shift all the bits over to the left by 1 position. Thus, `1000` would become `0000`. This is like multiplying by two (although in this case we get overflow!),

Then we want to right shift '>>' by 1, which would shift all the bits to the right by 1 position. In this case, it would become `0000` as the sign bit is replicated when you right shift. If it was `1111` it would become `1111`. This is like dividing by two, except in some cases, as you must be weary of the sign bit copying over.

Comment: MIN_VALUE is actually 1 followed by zeroes IE 1000 for 4 bits. All 1s will always be -1 regardless of word length.

Comment: oh god, you're right, I screwed that up completely. I'll fix that